# Wordpress URL change

Tags: url, url-rewriting, wordpress

I have recently moved my wordpress site from "test.xxxxxx.com" to "xxxxxx.com"  They are both identical except I just want to get rid of the "test" portion of my url on my index page and all my links.  They are both on the same FTP and server.  I transferred my site and have the homepage url working correctly but when I click on any of the links it still says "test" in front of the url.  I have tried a couple different search and replace plugins with no luck.  Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Did you update the URLs in Settings->General?

Comment: Yes I have but when I do that all of my links stop working

Comment: Did you also update the `WP_SITEURL` constant in wp-config.php?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a problem that it doesn't update the permalinks easily. So, maybe you will have to change the permalinks manually in the wordpress database.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin in order to fix old urls in your database.

After downloading and activating the plugin, you juste have to type old url to find and by which url to replace it, in your case you have to do it twice :

```
test.xxxxxx.com to xxxxxx.com
```

and

```
test.xxxxxx.com/ to xxxxxx.com/
```

I advice to do it twice because sometimes the plugin make difference between these two (strict string comparison I think) and wil not modifiy everything with only one command